# C++ How to properly access dynamic array elements using class method

Tags: c++, getter-setter, dynamic-arrays

I've created a class Student which contains a dynamic array. I've filled the first two items with the constructor. Every method I've tried to use to access/print those two elements from the main get a read/access violation and crashes. I've added a cout in the constructor that shows the elements ARE filled and exist. I've included two failed methods in the main: A void function that attempts to send first element to cout, and a method that accepts an int for the desired index. Both have been commented out to allow a test run showing elements are created and printed by the constructor.

Header:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define ARRAY_MAX 15
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string firstName, lastName;
    unsigned int ID, numItems = 0;
    typedef string* StringPtr;
    StringPtr items;

public:
    int capacity = 15;
    Student();
    Student(const string fName, const string lName, const unsigned int id);
    string getfName() const;
    string getlName() const;
    void getItem(int num);
    string getItemB(int num) const;
    unsigned int getID() const;
};
#endif // STUDENT_H
```

Definitions:

```
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student()
{
}

Student::Student(const string fName, const string lName, const unsigned int id)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    ID = id;

    StringPtr items = new string[capacity];
    numItems = 0;
    items[0] = "stuff";
    items[1] = "things";
    cout << items[0] << endl << items[1] << endl;
}

string Student::getfName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

string Student::getlName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

void Student::getItem(int num)
{
    cout << items[0] << endl;
}

string Student::getItemB(int num) const
{
    return items[num];
}

unsigned int Student::getID() const
{
    return ID;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    Student stu;
    string str;

    stu = Student("John", "Smith", 1200);
    cout << stu.getfName() << " " << stu.getlName() << endl;
    //stu.getItem(0);
    //cout << stu.getItemB(0);

    system("pause");

    // Quit without error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to do a `deep copy` not just `shallow` by overloading the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your code?

Comment: Expanding on @Raindrop7 's comment: `stu = Student("John", "Smith", 1200);` is a construction of a temporary followed by assignment of the  temporary, not an initialization with only a call to a constructor.

Comment: Compile your code with `-fsanitize=address` and you'll get useful diagnostic information.

Comment: In my get method I've tried memcpy to create a new fixed array of the same size and pass the correct element, and also just assigning something like:    string abc = items[num]; return abc   do these not copy the value of items[num]?

Comment: `memcpy` is a C function. It is too simple to handle most C++ objects. All it does is reproduce exactly whatever you pass it, similar to the default copy and assignment operators. consider `string`. A simple `string` implementation is a wrapper around a pointer to an array of characters and some book-keeping variables like the length of the string. If you copy it stupidly, you wind up with two `string`s pointing at the same character array, and that's a disaster as soon as one of the `string`s changes its contents or is destroyed. Running out of space.

Comment: You need to use `string`s constructors and operators to safely copy a `string`. Only `string` knows how to handle `string`s data. `memcpy` predates C++ and has no clue that constructors exist. [`std::copy` does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), as do all of C++'s standard library containers, and the helper functions in `<algorithm>` and `<utility>`.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Change

```
StringPtr items = new string[capacity];
```

into

```
items = new string[capacity];
```

## TL;DR

In

```
Student::Student(const string fName, const string lName, const unsigned int id)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    ID = id;

    StringPtr items = new string[capacity];
    numItems = 0;
    items[0] = "stuff";
    items[1] = "things";
    cout << items[0] << endl << items[1] << endl;
}
```

The line

```
    StringPtr items = new string[capacity];
```

creates a new Automatic (local) variable `items` and initializes it rather than the intended `private` member variable `StringPtr items;`. This is commonly known as [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). The local `items` goes out of scope at the end of the function leaking the allocated memory and the member `items` is never initialized leading to `stu.getItem(0);` accessing an uninitialized pointer and triggering the crash.

```
void Student::getItem(int num)
{
    cout << items[0] << endl; // items points Crom knows where, so items[0] is invalid.
}
```

This crash is quite fortunate. Accessing an unitintialized pointer results in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means it could do anything from looking like it works to causing the universe to explode.

The next problem you have to deal with is observing [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

[The best way to deal with this is `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<string> items;
```

`std::vector` is Rule of Three ([Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), actually) compliant so that you don't have to be.

If `std::vector` is not allowed, you need to implement a copy constructor

```
Student::Student(const Student & src):
    firstName(src.firstName), lastName(src.lastName),
    ID(src.ID), numItems(src.numItems),
    items(new string[capacity])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < src.numItems; i++)
    {
        items[i] = src.items[i];
    }
}
```

and an assignment operator (Taking advantage of the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for simplicity)

```
Student & Student::operator=(Student src)
{
    swap(*this,src);
    return *this;
}
```

Writing `swap` I'll leave up to you.

Comment: So how would I ensure that the private member variable was the one initialized and filled rather than creating a new local variable?

Comment: @JustinScott Point made though. I left the solution out of the answer and that makes for a pretty weak answer.